# Why can't I enter text into my input element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

It was working fine, but it stopped working.

```
const SearchBar = ({ carddata}) => {
  let arr = [];
  
  function searchResult(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (e.target.value === "") return;
          arr = [];
        carddata.filter((result) => {
          if (`${result.heading}`.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value)) {
              arr.push(result);
              console.log(arr)
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input
        onKeyDown={searchResult}
        className="search-input w-100   br bb fw4"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search here..."
      ></input>

      <SearchIcon
        className="search-icon h2 br bb hover-black"
        style={{ fill: "red" }}
        sx={{ fontSize: 40 }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it stop working" ? like what's the error message/strange behavior you noticed ?

Comment: Input is a self closing tag. Maybe it helps!?

Comment: And maybe it would be better to use a contorlled input with using searchValue and setSearchValue, and using a useEffect at onBlur synthetic event.

Comment: i can't type in input tag now but before 30 minutes it was working fine i restarted my pc, i don't know what happend

Comment: I cant see the value, and onChange, and state variables, are you sure all the code in included the in question

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` attribute in your`input` tag to update.

```
<input
value={somestate}
onChange={e=> setState(e.target.value)}
/>
```

This will update the value in your input as   you type.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are not passing the  event to the function when writing `onKeyDown`, try passing the event to the function like this and see if it would work:

```
<input
    onKeyDown={(e)=>searchResult(e)}
    className="search-input w-100   br bb fw4"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search here..."
  ></input>
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation. Please see [answer].

Answer (score -1):

I made you an example, but i couldn't tor try it if you share the content of carddate array, maybe i can solve and explain it more detailed!

You cen read more about the controlled inputs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const SearchBar = ({ carddata}) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue]

  let arr = [];
  
  useEffect()=>{
    function searchResult() {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        if (searchValue === "") return;
            arr = [];
          carddata.filter((result) => {
            if (`${result.heading}`.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value)) {
                arr.push(result);
                console.log(arr)
          }
        });
      }
    }, [searchValue]
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input
        onChange={e=>setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        className="search-input w-100 br bb fw4"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search here..."
        value="searchValue"
      />

      <SearchIcon
        className="search-icon h2 br bb hover-black"
        style={{ fill: "red" }}
        sx={{ fontSize: 40 }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```